# Mysql to Mysqli having hard time converting code

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm watching some tutorials a couple years old by Alex of phpacademy.org and he is use mysql instead of mysqli I know mysqli is better and should be used instead but can't seem to figure out how to make this code work with all mysqli instead. Can someone convert it?

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass') or die (mysqli_error());
mysql_select_db('jquery');

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    if (!empty($username)) {
        $username_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'");
        $username_result = mysql_result($username_query, 0);

        if ($username_result == 0) {
            echo 'Username is available!';
        } else if ($username_result == 1) {
            echo 'Sorry, that username is taken.';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

What I tried to do is this.. but `mysqli_result` kept giving me errors:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'jquery') or die (mysqli_error());

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['username']);
    if (!empty($username)) {
        $username_query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'");
        $username_result = mysqli_result($username_query, 0);

        if ($username_result == 0) {
            echo 'Username is available!';
        } else if ($username_result == 1) {
            echo 'Sorry, that username is taken.';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

so the only error I kept getting is from `mysqli_result` saying:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result() in \php\username.php on line 8

I looked up uses of `mysqli_result` online and haven't found many results to help me figure this out hopefully someone here can help me.

Comment: Please don't use tags that don't apply to your question

Comment: It asked me to put 5 so after running out after 3 I decided to add others since a lot of the time when quests are asked people ask what web server and all that they are using so I put apache for that reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$username_query` is of the [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) class when you use the object oriented style; `mysqli_result` is a class and not a function.

To get a row from your result set you can do (for example):

```
$username_result = mysqli_fetch_array($username_query);
```

And the reason you should use mysqli (or PDO) instead of the `mysql_*` functions is not just that the latter are deprecated: PDO (and mysqli) offer prepare statements and that offers better protection against sql injection than the escape functions.

Comment: I will research mysqli_fetch_array and see if I can get that to work for me. Does it return true or false in anyway?

Comment: @JoeBobJr. An array or `NULL` when there are no more rows.

Comment: When I echo $username_result = mysqli_fetch_array($username_query); it echoes Array to my page. Not sure how I can even use that. Still trying to figure it out thanks for the response.

Comment: @JoeBobJr. You are fetching an array, so the result is an array. Just do a `var_dump()` instead of an `echo` and you will probably see you can find the result in `$username_result[0]`

Comment: Yup that var_dump showed me exactly what I needed thanks. Just needed to change my. if ($username_result == '0') to if ($username_result[0] == '0') works perfect now.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure first that the username column in your table is `unique` so that there wont be duplicate usernames and therefore `$count` would be exactly either 0 or 1, then try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] != '') {

    $connect = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'jquery') or die (mysqli_error());
    $username       = $_POST['username'];
    $query          = "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) AS count FROM `users` WHERE `username`=?";
    $username_query = $connect->prepare($query);
    $username_query->bind_param('s', $username);
    $username_query->execute();
    $username_query->bind_result($count);
    $username_query->fetch();
    $username_query->close();
    $connect->close();

    if ($count == 0) {
        echo 'Username is available!';
    } else if ($count == 1) {
        echo 'Sorry, that username is taken.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Unexpected ) in line 7 that I fixed. Then line 8 has errors I commented line 8 out then line 9 has errors. This code has many errors and nothing like I code. I've never seen so many -> in one code like that.

Comment: yes there were 2 typos are fixed now which anyone with basic knowledge could fix them, as for the `->` you should read more before jumping to conclusions http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php , the code is working and i tested it on my server fyi

Comment: This is a very thorough example and includes binding not only query parameters but results. The `->` shows up a lot due to using the object-oriented interface, which is usually easier to follow than the procedural one once you get used to it. Adding comments might help explain what's going on here.

Comment: It works now that I tried it but earlier it didn't work at all. It kept giving me errors on the line with the bind_param. I was able to get help from someone above to use my own changing very few things. I'm used to coding the old way this way is very confusing for me.

Comment: It's a shame I can't pick both answers as correct since they both work. Sorry about that.